# How do I set up a difference in difference model - Effect of political party on public policies?

Tags: difference-in-difference

This is the first time I work with difference in difference and I cannot understand how to even start the setup. I want to know the effect of the political party of the USA president on a public policy, for example let's suppose that after having a Republican president, a Democratic president is elected. I thought that I could apply a DD design.

I am thinking that the treatment starts with the election, and it is present at the same time for all,  so I would have treatment group after the election and control group before. But than what can I set as "before" and "after" group? I just feel very confused and I have been on this for 2 days.

Sorry for any imprecision but again, it's the first time I work with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So the DiD assumes that the Treatment (T) and Control (C) group have the same (linear) trend. Using the C group you can estimate a so called counterfactual for the T group. This counterfactual is the outcome for the T group had the treatment not happened. Now you can take the difference between the T outcome during a treatment and the counterfactual and you have your treatment effect.

But having said all this, the question is how do you want to setup the framework with elections? You could compare two states that had very similar results in the previous election. You would assume that this election you expect similar/equal results, but due to a (or some) new campaign(s) of one party the result is different than last year.

Or you have some pools shortly before the official election and here you pick two areas/states that show equal/similar results. Now there is a treatment from one party (some kind of campaign, maybe through facebook....) and in the final election the result differs from the pool taken prior to the final election.

To be honest both approaches are not very solid in my opinion, but it might be good enough for a homework at the University or something.

I hope that helps a bit and gives you some ideas.